# VS code, is there a way to count the files by type? say I need to count the "ts" files in my project

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my huge project, I would like to count the ".ts" file(s) existence. as well ".spec.ts" files. how to I count them separately. is there a way in "visual studio code" for it? simply counting the file by it's extension.

at present I am trying with "ctl + shif+ f" but not works.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Not as a built-in functionality. But there is for instance the [File Count extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MikeCluck.file-count) which may support your use case ...

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> is a good enough approach, if the total amount of files that you will potentially match is less than 10000. This is due to a [limitation in vscode](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/29120), that limits the total amount of matches to this number. Thanks to [@Timothy G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6530134/timothy-g) for pointing this out!

I would do it like this:

To count all `.spec.ts` files change the search pattern to regex and search for `(.*\n?)*` (this matches the whole content of the file, forcing a multi-line match in vscode).

Under "files to include" add `*.spec.ts`:

[image]

To count all `*.ts` files without the `*.spec.ts` files you set "files to include" to `*.ts` and "files to exclude" to `*.spec.ts`:

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this is really a good way.  I get 10000 results (the max VS Code shows), but only in 6 files, which I know my project has way more than 6.

Comment: You are right! Turns out that vscode has a limit on possible matches, set to 10000 . I updated this answer with a regex that matches the whole file content. I believe this way it can still be a useful approach for projects that have less then 10000 *.ts files to match.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the file system in your OS ?
In Windows you could search for *.ts and you could see the amount of elements in the bottom left corner of the window.

On linux you could use `ls --file-type *.ts | wc --lines`

Comment: you have to use `find`, `ls` with `*.ts` uses shell expansion and that does not traverse sub directories